# Validate null fields in prepared statement

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc

I have a GUI that takes in fields that get inserted inside a query. When the fields are empty, it's expected that java throws a format exception when the fields don't match the specified type. However, I would like the user to know that the input is invalid. Is there a way to validate when the fields inserted in the prepared statement are empty?

**Snippet:**

```
String query = "DELETE FROM racewinners WHERE racename = ? "
    + "AND raceyear = ? AND ridername = ? "
+ "AND distance = ? " + "AND winning_time = ?";

    try {
        statement = connection.prepareStatement(query);
        statement.setString(1, race_name);
        statement.setInt(2, race_year);
        statement.setString(3, rider_name);
        statement.setInt(4, distance);
        statement.setObject(5, winning_time);

    } catch(SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e1.getMessage());
    }
```

Comment: You could do it in your table's schema as `not null`, but ideally you would do it in application logic. Just throw an exception if either of the inputs are `null`. Use `Objects.requireNonNull`.

Comment: I don't understand your question. What stops you from writing such validation?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis could you illustrate an example. It's easy to validate empty fields by calling ```.getText().length == 0``` but in this case it's slightly different. These fields are expected to have that type. How can I check to see if either of those fields are null? Would this possibly be within the query?

Comment: @PM77-1 I'm not sure how to handle this case. I don't want the formatException to get thrown. Instead I want to inform the user that the fields are null and or empty.

Comment: If you don't want users to be exposed to Java run-time exceptions,  then catch them yourself and either throw your own ones instead or select any other way to communicate with users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check for `null`, since Java 7, all you have to do is

```
Objects.requireNonNull(someVariable);
```

or use the [overloaded method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#requireNonNull%28T,%20java.lang.String%29) where you can specify a message. The method will throw an exception if the argument passed is `null`.

For any other custom logic, you'll have to write your own validator.

Something like

```
public interface Validator<T> {
    public void validate(T object, Errors errors);
}

public class RaceInfoValidator implements Validator<RaceInfo> {
    public void validate(RaceInfo raceInfo, Error errors) {
        if (raceInfo.getRaceName() == null) {
            errors.addError("Must provide a race name.";
        } else if (raceInfo.getRaceName().isEmpty()) {
            errors.addError("The race name must not be empty.";
        }
        // etc.
    }
}

...

String race_name = ...;
...
RaceInfo raceInfo = new RaceInfo(race_name, ...);
RaceInfoValidator validator = ...;
Errors errors = ...; // write some implementation
validator.validate(raceInfo, errors);
if (errors.hasErrors()) {
    // show user the errors
}
```

---

Alternatively, you could put this validation in the database table schemas, but I don't recommend it.

Comment: So in this case I would pass in ```statement```. As for the message, I'm going to use an JOptionPane.

Comment: @TheGrayFox From what I understand in your question, you want to check if `race_name`, `race_year`, etc. are `null`. So that's what you would pass.

Comment: That's going to be a lot of repetition, let me look more into this method. The formatException still gets thrown. I basically don't want this to happen and have the validation inform me of empty fields.

Comment: @TheGrayFox Consider encapsulating all that logic in a `Validator` class.

Comment: Good idea, and that would make for some abstraction. I'm just unsure of how to begin. Could you perhaps give an example just so I have an idea as to how to set this up properly. And thanks for the feedback.

Comment: @TheGrayFox Are the various `race_name`, `race_year`, etc. fields part of an object of some class, like a `RaceInfo` class? If they are, just create a `Validator<RaceInfo>` which has a `validate(RaceInfo info)` method which might return a `Errors` object containing all the errors.

Comment: No they're just encapsulated variables inside of an actionListener to make them more readable. Example:    ```String race_name = (String) winners_combo_box.getSelectedItem();```

Comment: @TheGrayFox _Encapsulate everything_ :)

Comment: Alright, just show me what you mean in your edit. Unfortunately, I'm visual haha. One validation example will do!

Comment: @TheGrayFox Take a look. I've left some stuff out. It's better that you try to figure it out yourself.